# In Trello, is there a way to search across all of an organization's boards?

Tags: trello, search

"Search and Filter Cards" searches only the cards on the current board, as the name suggests. I would like to be able to search across all the boards of the organization, (subject to board membership and permissions).

Answer (score 1):

You can search across the names of cards, boards and members from the [search page](https://trello.com/search) or by manually specifying the search term in the querystring:

```
https://trello.com/search?q=trello
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict the search to a particular organization, which was mentioned in the OP's question.